# React js - having problems creating a todo list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a todo list where after you finish one task,
only then will the next task be enabled (to tick as finished).

Here is what I have so far:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
$(function(){
var tasks = [
  {title: "Wake up"},
  {title: "Eat dinner"},
  {title: "Go to sleep"}
];
var Task = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {locked:true, done:false}  
    },
    handleClick: function(e){
        this.setState({done: !this.state.done});  
        var selector = '.toggle[data-order="'+(this.props.order+1)+'"]';
        this.setState({locked: true})
        console.log(selector)
        console.log($(selector).removeAttr("disabled"))

    },
    render: function() {

      var locked;
      //Fix first task to not be disabled
      if(this.props.order == 0 && this.state.done === false)
        locked = false;
      else
        locked = this.state.locked;
      var done = this.state.done ? "Done":"Not done";
      var classView = "task" + (this.state.done ? " done":" not-done");
      return (
          <div class="todo well well-sm" class={classView}>
            <span class="description">{this.props.title}</span>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick} data-order={this.props.order} disabled={locked} class="toggle btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>&nbsp;Done
            </button>
          </div>
      );
    }
});
var TaskList = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var i = -1;
    var taskNodes = this.props.data.map(function (task) {
      return <Task title={task.title} order={++i} />;
    });
    return (
      <div class="task-list">
       {taskNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
var Guider = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <TaskList data={this.props.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.renderComponent(<Guider data={tasks} />, document.body);
});
```

The next buttons are still not disabled, and I feel that I'm doing something wrong in general (not in accordance with the react "zen").

Btw:
How can I change the state for a dom element without the user triggering it? is there any id I should use?

Comment: I would declare handleClick inside `TaskList` and pass it as props to `Task` and call that. This will allow you to change state of other Tasks.

Comment: You shouldn't define _everything_ in `DOMReady` like that, just the instantiation of your code. This will make it run faster!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you initiate the data into non-root component, it becomes hard to update other components. So I prefer keeping data into root component, Then pass a click handler as props. Now you'll have access to that handler inside non-root component. Calling that will update root component and so the other non-root components.

Here's working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ammit/wBYHY/5/

### Example -

```
var Task = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function (e) {
    // Passing order of task
    this.props.clicked(order);
  },
  render: function () {
    return ( <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}></button> );
  }
});


var TaskList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    // initiate tasks here
  },
  whenClicked: function(order){
    // Revise the tasks using `order`
    // Finally do a setState( revised_tasks );
  },
  render: function(){
    return ( <Task clicked={this.whenClicked} /> );
  }
});
```

Comment: When triggering 'this.props.clicked(order);' will it call 'whenClicked' ? and how after that can I enable the next task? (how can I access that dom element?)

Comment: I'd just add that I usually prefer to keep the naming schemes for things the same as in-built elements in react.  So for example rather than using the prop `clicked` it would be better if it was called `onClick` for consistency.  Then you always know if it's a built-in or custom component that `onClick={this.handler}` is what you need to do.  There's no conflicts with using the same naming convention that occur.