# React.js: onClick function from child to parent

Tags: javascript, onclick, reactjs

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js) article as an example (React way), but it is not working for me. Please point me to my mistake, as I can't understand what's wrong.

This is the error I see:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onClick is not a function

Here is my code:

```
// PARENT
var SendDocModal = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {tagList: []};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.tagList.map(function(item) {
            return (
              <TagItem nameProp={item.Name} idProp={item.Id} onClick={this.HandleRemove}/>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  },
  HandleRemove: function(c) {
    console.log('On REMOVE = ', c);
  }
});

// CHILD
var TagItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <span className="react-tagsinput-tag">
        <span>{this.props.nameProp}</span>
        <a className='react-tagsinput-remove' onClick={this.HandleRemove}></a>
      </span>
    )
  },
  HandleRemove: function() {
    this.props.onClick(this);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Whoops! sorry.I always get an error:  Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onClick is not a function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `this` inside the `map` callback does not refer to the React component, hence `this.HandleRemove` is `undefined`.

You can set the `this` value explicitly by passing a second argument to `map`:

```
this.state.tagList.map(function() {...}, this);
```

Now `this` *inside* the callback refers to the same value as `this` *outside* the callback, namely the `SendDocModal` instance.

This has nothing to do with React, it's just how JavaScript works. See [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for more info and other solutions.

Comment: Hi, Felix. Thanks for your reply. Tried without for loop(just a component with hardcoded props) and it worked great. But I don't understand how to pass the context in my case. Could you please describe this in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, simply confused forEach and map. It's the same solution. Have a look at the link in my answer to learn more about `this`.

Comment: If I understood right I should do something like this:                                             `code {this.state.tagList.map(function(item){
        return(
         <TagItem nameProp={item.Name} idProp={item.Id} contextProp={this} onClick={this.HandleRemove}/>
        )
       }, this)}, ` but in this case I get the same : Uncaught TypeError: this.props.contextProp.props.onClick is not a function

Comment: No, just implement the solution in my answer. The body of the callback stays the same.

Comment: aha, now I got it. the correct code will be: `code {this.state.tagList.map(function(item){
        return(
         <TagItem nameProp={item.Name} idProp={item.Id}  onClick={this.HandleRemove}/>
        )
       }, this)} `

Comment: But actually I didn't got it. if this stands now for parent component, how I'm passing child's "this" to parent, if now "this" stands for the reference to parent -) I'm totally confused.

Comment: Every function has its own `this`. Really the only issue was that you were *not* passing a function to `TagItem` because `this` inside the `map` callback did not refer to the `SendDocModal` component. By setting `this` of the callback correctly, `this.HandleRemove` inside the `map` callback now correctly references the `HandleRemove` method of `SendDocModal`. That's all to it.

Comment: This just saved my life +1 dude

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    var SendDocModal = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {

            var item = {};
            item.Name = 'First';
            item.Id = 123;

            var item2 = {};
            item2.Name = 'Second';
            item2.Id = 123456;
            return {tagList: [item,item2]};
        },

        HandleRemove: function(c){
            console.log('On REMOVE = ', c);
        },

        render: function() {
            return (<div>
                {this.state.tagList.map(function(item){
                    return(
                            <TagItem nameProp={item.Name} idProp={item.Id} key={item.Id} click={this.HandleRemove}/>
                    )}, this)}
                    </div>
            )       
        }

    });
    // CHILD
    var TagItem = React.createClass({

        handleClick: function(nameProp)
        {
            this.props.click(nameProp);
        },


        render: function(){
            return(
                <span className="react-tagsinput-tag" ><span onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.nameProp)}>{this.props.nameProp}</span><a className='react-tagsinput-remove' ></a></span>
            )
        }
    });
```

Few changes:

Added 'this' after the tagList mapping. To be honest I am not entirely sure why - perhaps a more experienced programmer can tell us.

Added a key to each TagItem. This is recommended and an the console will inform you that you should do this so that if the state changes, React can track each item accordingly.

The click is passed through the props. See [React js - having problems creating a todo list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427869/react-js-having-problems-creating-a-todo-list)

Comment: Yeah, the same as Felix advised. slightly more detailed. Thanks a lot, will try to understand "this" concept, looks so different from Java...

Comment: No problem. Check out this: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes